# Storing reference/accessing page instance from static content

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference, static

Since I haven't been programming for too long I will first write my assumptions as it is possible that my theory is not quite right.

Assumptions:

1. Following simple logic behind reference type, if I have an instance of class 'Class1', called A, and create a new variable of type Class1: Class1 newInstance = A, every change in class A's attributes should be reflected in 'newInstance' attributes as class is reference type (as opposed to value type, for example in structs).
2. In asp, every page is a new instance of a class of type Page, otherwise every client would see and act on the same page, and the goal is to separate them. Every component of the page (like textBox or gridView) belongs to a particular instance.
   Please correct me if these are wrong.

Problem:
As I am forced to use page methods to get some of the data from client side (javascript) I have no choice but to use static methods. What I want to achieve is to be able to store instance of the page, or at least some sort of reference, in a session variable so then I can later get back to it and get or set values for particular controls in the desired page instance.
So what I've done is: I store current instance (this) in a session variable. This is only assigned once (!isPostback) on PageLoad.
Following the logic of reference type, every change in the instance of the page should be reflected in the session variable, but somehow it is not. If there's a change in some control's values, I can easily see that they are reflected in the instance of the page on postBack (as they should), however the content of my session variable is not being changed. It's behaving as if it was a struct.
The same happens when I'm trying to store the instance in the static class variable (although that would not be a solution even if it worked, as it's a multi-user web app).

Could anyone explain to me what is going on, and correct my thinking if it's wrong.

Comment: this should help you i guess. http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/

Comment: So, according to the article, does it mean that in my session variable I'm actually storing a reference to instance of page that doesn't exist anymore as it is re-instantiated from __ViewState at every postback?